# I want Select into listview and column calculate with textbox

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(@"Select StockID,FoodId,StockName,StockDate,
                               StockNum,UnID,StockMin,StockCalulate 
                               from StockCalutale", Conn);
try
{
    int currency = int.Parse(txtAmount.Text);
    SqlDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(dr["StockID"].ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(dr["FoodId"].ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(dr["StockName"].ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(dr["StockDate"].ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(dr["StockNum"].ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(dr["UnID"].ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(dr["StockMin"].ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(dr["StockCalulate"].ToString()* txtAmount.Text);

        listView1.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "EROR");
}
```

Comment: You can't multiply a string with another string. Doesn't make sense also if the two strings contain numbers. C# has no automatic conversion of this kind like VB.NET (luckily) You need both strings to be converted in a number and then make the multiplication. One is already converted.

Comment: What is your _exact_ problem? Where do you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
item.SubItems.Add(dr["StockCalulate"].ToString()* txtAmount.Text);
```

You can't multiply a string with another string. Doesn't make sense also if the two strings contain numbers. C# has no automatic conversion of this kind like VB.NET (luckily) You need both strings to be converted in a number and then make the multiplication. One is already converted albeit is an *exception ready* way.

```
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(@"Select StockID,FoodId,StockName,StockDate,
                               StockNum,UnID,StockMin,StockCalulate 
                               from StockCalutale", Conn);
try
{
    int currency = 0;

    // When input comes from the user don't trust its ability with the keyboard
    // use a foolproof way to check its input....
    if(!Int32.TryParse(txtAmount.Text, out currency))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid currency value!");
        return;
    }

    SqlDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        // Also this line is risky. I assume that you never have null values
        // in this StockCalulate field otherwise you need to check with dr.IsDbNull
        int value = Convert.ToInt32(dr["StockCalulate"].ToString());
        int newStock = value * currency;

        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(dr["StockID"].ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(dr["FoodId"].ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(dr["StockName"].ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(dr["StockDate"].ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(dr["StockNum"].ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(dr["UnID"].ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(dr["StockMin"].ToString());

        item.SubItems.Add(newStock.ToString());
        listView1.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "EROR");
}
```

By the way, I am not sure about the datatype to use here, if you need to keep decimals then consider to use a decimal datatype and the equivalent conversions methods (decimal.TryParse and Convert.ToDecimal).

Comment: I'm Try but Eror At  item.SubItems.Add(newStock);  Line is Red

Comment: Forget to add ToString()